# nutch crawler is crawling ' as â€

Tags: java, nutch

nutch crawler is crawling `let's` as `Letâ€™s` y??? is there is any setting to change the this charset..

Answer (score 1):

`â€™` is the UTF-8 encoding of the single closing quote (not the apostrophe), and you're interpreting it as Windows-1252.  You need to use the right encoding (UTF-8).  [This link](http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/GettingNutchRunningWithUtf8) may help.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used Nutch myself, but [this page](http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/GettingNutchRunningWithUtf8) looks like it's relevant:

> To enable passing of UTF-8 characters, edit $TOMCAT/conf/server.xml. Locate the <Connector> tag for the web (look for "8080") and insert this parameter assignment: URIEncoding="UTF-8" as explained in Tomcat 5 FAQ at http://tomcat.apache.org/faq/connectors.html#utf8

Comment: i dont think that is because of tomcat because my cmd prompt is also showing the same thing...

Comment: i checked with both terminal(in ubuntu) and with tomcat

Comment: @ragaa: But *how* did you check with the terminal? What did you do? (I'm not saying this is the problem, but you never know.)